# How to recursively get all the links present in a website using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for the way to recursively find all the links present on any given website. I know how to do this in java but I don't know how it can be done using javascript.

[Consider this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFgdy.png) represents a website directory and if we provide 'www.abc.com' ,then it should return following output.

---

```
www.abc.com\images
www.abc.com\files
www.abc.com\images\a.jpg
www.abc.com\images\b.jpg
www.abc.com\files\aa.txt
www.abc.com\files\bb.txt
```

Comment: Do you want to collect all links from the first page, then follow them, if they are pointing to the same base website address and continue collecting there and so on? Or what do you mean be recursively.

Comment: exactly! I want to collect all the links present in that website having same base website address.and so on.

Comment: with nodeJs? Or directly from the user's browser?

Comment: directly from the user browser. let's consider it as a webpage where you can input url of any website and it'll display all the links present in the website.

Comment: What if links are implemented by JavaScript and not by `<a href>` tags, or they are added dynamically & asynchronously?

Comment: What if a web page has a `base` tag, or dynamically alters the `href` addresses on the page? This is too broad a question, as this is no easy task at all.

Comment: @trincot we have to only find links with <a href> tags. let's say it doesn't contain any dynamically added links.

Comment: You'll still bump into cross-origin limitations. I supopose you tried with Ajax calls? What happened?

Comment: @trincot No, i haven't .but, we can get html content of given url using ajax and place the result inside a div. after that we can  find all the <a href> tags present inside that div using getElementsByTagName("a") and store them(links) in an array.for each elements in array we follow the same steps . fetch html content,find href tags, and store it in array.But it will be time consuming.don't you think?

Comment: Not only that, but unless you are on the same domain, your Ajax calls will be refused on most sites (cf. cross origin resource sharing).

Comment: @trincot if you had to do it for simpler website that doesn't contain any dynamic links, only html tags, how would you do it?

Comment: If there is no dynamic content, not JavaScript with alerts, ... etc, then you could load a page in a `iframe`, and collect the links there, filter them to only keep those on the same site, and recurse. But this is just theory, since a high proportion of web sites are dynamic.

Comment: ...and keep in mind CORS

Comment: i don't think there's any method to find elements inside iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is tagged jQuery, I'll use that. Simply target the `a` tags.

```
var linksList = [];
function addLink(url){
    if(url!= "" && linksList.indexOf(url) == -1){
        links.list.push(url);
        scrapePage(url);
    }
}
function scrapePage(url){
    $.get(url,function(html){
        var $iframe = $('body').append('iframe');
        $iframe.contents().find("body").html(html);
        $iframe.contents().find("body a").each(function(index,link){
            addLink(link.href);
        });
        $iframe.remove();
    });
}
$("body a").each(function(index,link){
    addLink(link.href);
});
```

Pretty simple, a function to add links in our list, another to follow the links we add. I decided to put the content of the scraped page inside an iframe to keep everything restrained...

You'll want to add your logic to make sure it takes only links that are from the domain. You might need to play with the URL as it will not be absolute (but considered it is in my code). And so on.

Comment: I said recursively. which means i want all the links present in that website including the links present in its child pages and so on until all the links are discovered.

Comment: "recursively" does NOT imply that at all... You should spend some time clarifying your question then.

Answer (score -1):

In js getElementsByTagName("a")

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

In jquery $("a")

Answer (score -1):

I think you cannot get all the links of a particular website. But you can get all the link of particular page like below :-

```
var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Hope it helps. It would be great if you elaborate your issue more.

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try http://www.nightmarejs.org/ to get all the all the links of a website.